# How to get the element of a list with the same name?

Tags: r

I would like to create a list of objects with possibly duplicated names. For example:

```
l <- list("a"=1:4, "a"=2:3, "b"=1)
```

Now I want to get elements of l whose name is "a" (l[1] and l[2] in this case). Is there any concise way to do that instead of looping over names(l)? Thanks.

Comment: Would you be offended if one pries and and asks what the ultimate goal is?

Comment: @RicardoSaporta My goal is to create a tree structure to hold hierarchical data. And some of the names of the nodes can be duplicated. You have a better idea than list of lists? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use basic subsetting for this:

```
> l[names(l) == "a"]
$a
[1] 1 2 3 4

$a
[1] 2 3
```

---

*(By the way, `l` is a funky character to use by itself with scripts because of how easily it can be misinterpreted for `1`).*

Comment: With a `here be dragons` caveat that duplicate names are non-standard, and you can't expect `extract` by name functions to work consistently.